# Creating SQL Server database and tables from visio 2010 professional (Forward Engineer)

Tags: sql-server, visio

I have designed a database with Visio 2010 Professional. I am now looking for a way to actually create a database and tables. something like [this](http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/)  However Forward engineer executable seems broken. Is there any other utility that can create a Database for me by looking at visio schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this Visio add-in all the time and do not have any problems.

What issues are you having?

Comment: I was getting this error; but it's been fixed since. thank you http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/workitem/213